# How to check an array of forbidden words?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the label red if a user enters a forbidden word on keyup. I can do this with one word, but no matter what I've tried I've failed badly when it comes to multiple.

This is my code:

```
username.onkeyup = function() {

    var forbiddenWords = ["ffff, aaaa, bbbb, hhhh, ggggg"];
    var username_value = this.value.split('');

    function isForbiddenWord(value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenWords.length; i++) {
            var rgx = new RegExp(forbiddenWords[i], 'gi');
            if (rgx.test(value)) {
                return true;   
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isForbiddenWord(this.value) == true) {
        console.log('Username contains swearing word. Please, remove it');
        document.getElementById('username_label').style.color = "red";
    }
    else {
        if (username_value[username_value.length - 1] === "-" || username_value[username_value.length - 1] === "_") {
            console.log('Username cannot end in dash (-) or underscore (_)');
            this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
        }
        else if (this.value.length < 4) {
            console.log('Username cannot be less than 4 characters');
            document.getElementById('username_label').style.color = "red";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('username_label').style.color = "green";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: simple way w/o looping: `isForbiddenWord=/./.test.bind(RegExp( "\\b("+["ffff", "aaaa", "bbbb", "hhhh", "ggggg"].join(")|(")+")\\b")`

Comment: I have 30 forbidden words...

Comment: RegExp can handle 30 words. or 300. probably 3000... i'll take a native function over a user-land one anyday, and without looping and multiple test()ing, the one-shot is likely to be a lot faster. the only downside i can think of is if `forbiddenWords` changes between executions, you would need to rebuild the RegExp.

Comment: OK them, I'm going to save your code for a rainy day! Thanks @dandavis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array of forbidden words currently consists of 1 word: `"ffff, aaaa, bbbb, hhhh, ggggg"`. Your code works if you use this as the array:

```
var forbiddenWords = ["ffff", "aaaa", "bbbb", "hhhh", "ggggg"];
```

Comment: That is literally the lat thing that would cross my mind! A million thanks @M4tini!

Comment: You also need the fix @charlietfl posted, or it will only detect `"ffff"`

Comment: Right, I see why it will execute only the first one. If I do it the way @charlietfl posted wouldn't be false anyway? I mean if the word is forbidden return true and end the loop, then return false. That's what I understand.

Comment: A function can only return 1 thing, so if `return true` is reached, it will not get to the part where it returns false.

Comment: I understand it all now. Thanks @M4tini

Answer (score 3):

Try only returning false only after the loop is completed, not for each iterationas `else`. That way if any are true the return true will break the loop, otherwise when loop is done all will be determined to be false.

Right now as soon as the ***first*** false is encountered the function is returning false and will ignore any subsequent words in array

```
function isForbiddenWord(value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenWords.length; i++) {
        var rgx = new RegExp(forbiddenWords[i], 'gi');
        if (rgx.test(value)) {
            return true;   
        }
        // move this outside loop
        //else {
           // return false;
        //}
    }
    return false;
}
```

And as noted in other answer fix quotes in array

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: Just added extra line of text to explain difference. Run it through in your head...or in debugger in browser console. As soon as ***any*** false would be encountered that would be returned and the other words would not get tested

Comment: If I do it your way wouldn't be false anyway? I mean if the word is forbidden return true. When the loop ends, then return false. So, it's false... That's what I understand.

Comment: No...my way only returns false when ***all*** are false. Remember that only one `return` can ever be executed in a function. Once it is executed any code after it does not get executed

Comment: one suggestion: remove the `g` flag, it's not needed and can slow down some engines.